# API Яндекс.Карт 2.1: Как задать свою картинку метки?

Tags: javascript, яндекс-карты

Как задать свою картинку метки в API 2.1 Yandex.Maps. В документации Яндекс.Карт такое возможно, реализовано и показано примером для 1.x, но мне нужно для 2.1, потому что старые коды в нём не работают.

Кто-нибудь уже сталкивался с этим? Как решить?

**Обновление**

Смотрите,  у меня такой вод код. Данный код для одной фишки на карте, разные фишки могут быть с разными картинками, как мне в этот код интегрировать код картинок?

```
myMap.geoObjects
.add(myGeoObject);
.add(new ymaps.Placemark([$map_coords_1, $map_coords_2], {
balloonContent: '$map_content'
}, {
preset: 'islands#icon', //Тип фишки на карте
iconColor: '#$map_random' //Цвет фишки на карте. Думаю можно сделать рандомный
}))
```

Answer (score 2):

```
marker = new ymaps.Placemark(
          [latitude, longitude],
          { iconContent: ''
       ,hintContent: 'icom content'
       ,balloonContentHeader: 'balloon content'
       ,balloonContentBody: 'balloon content plus'  
      },
      { iconLayout: 'default#image'
       ,iconImageHref: ICON-IMAGE-REF
       ,iconImageSize: [10, 10]
       ,iconImageOffset: [-5, -5]
       ,Name: 'pm_'+MarkerList.getLength()
       ,data: ANY_DATA   
      });
```

`ICON-IMAGE-REF` - ссылка на изображение или изображение в формате

```
"data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhCgAKAH....."
```

`ANY_DATA` - любые данные, которые необходимы в процессе работы с картой

Comment: Смотрите,  у меня такой вод код. Данный код для одной фишки на карте, разные фишки могут быть с разными картинками, как мне в этот код интегрировать код картинок?

 myMap.geoObjects
.add(myGeoObject)";
.add(new ymaps.Placemark([$map_coords_1, $map_coords_2], {
balloonContent: '$map_content'
}, {
preset: 'islands#icon', //Тип фишки на карте
iconColor: '#$map_random' //Цвет фишки на карте. Думаю можно сделать рандомный
}))

Comment: Код картинки, видимо, передавать как-то нужно. Вы же передаете "$map_...." переменные. Таким образом передавать и ссылку на картинку.